# Create column with grouped means in r

Tags: r, mean, dplyr

so i have a dataset of countries that have a variable called "country wave" and another called "famsaved". I want a function that adds a column to the set that gives me the mean for "famsaved" for the country wave category. I know that in STATA the function is egen AverFamSave = mean(FamSavedThisYr01), by(Country Wave).... any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you have the `dplyr` package, which is part of the tidyverse, you can use use a combination of the `group_by()` and `summarize()` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` in `base R`

```
aggregate(FamSavedThisYr01~ Country + Wave, df1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

If we need to create a column, use `ave`

```
df1$MeanFamSavedThisYr01 <- with(df1, ave(FamSavedThisYr01, Country, Wave))
```

Comment: this works, but can i code it so in a new column the values appear for each observation?

Comment: @JuanCamiloRomero you can use `ave` where the default function is `mean`